# Declare python variable that stores a function, but not run it

Tags: python, function, variables, syntax, processing

I am trying to declare a python variable that stores a function with the desired parameters, but when I run it, it runs the last declared variable. I am trying to store it in a variable and when I write the variable name, it runs the function with parameters associated. It is meant to run in a program called Processing:

```
size(1000,500)
background(255,255,255)
cred = fill(255,0,0)
corange = fill(255,127,0)
cyellow = fill(255,255,0)
cgreen = fill(0,255,0)
cblue = fill(0,0,255)
cpurple = fill(143,0,255)

mcolors = [cred,corange,cyellow, cgreen, cblue, cpurple]
y=0

def palette():
    global y
    global mcolors
    for i in mcolors:
        i
        rect(0,y,20,20)
        y+=22
palette()   `
```

Comment: I don't quite follow.  The only function here is `palette` which doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: I guess none of the close voters can read because I understood the question just fine. Just as an FYI, `fill()` in Processing-like libraries sets a global fill color, so when the function is called it important. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think you already sort of have that behavior -- just assign to the globals and then run the function `palette`.

Comment: After some re-reading, I think I understand.  OP:  Are you asking how to defer running the `fill(...)` function until inside the loop in the `palette` function?  If so, please clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the calls in lambda functions:

```
cred = lambda: fill(255, 0, 0)
```

To call it you would still need the `()`, i.e.:

```
i()
```

However I think in this case it might be better to just store the color values rather than the actual function references, i.e.:

```
cred = (255, 0, 0)
```

This creates a *tuple* of the values (kind of like an immutable list). It's different from the function call parenthesis. Then later you could pass these to a function in your loop:

```
fill(*i)
```

The star operator will make it use the values from the tuple as separate arguments rather than one argument.

Comment: Yes I used the fill(*i). Thank you so much.